# Using XNamespace in XML Linq Select statement

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq, namespaces

My code used to only have to deal with one namespace, so this worked fine:

```
Imports <xmlns="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2">

Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load("my.xml")

Dim IDElemCollect As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = _
  From IdEl In doc ...<ItemID>.<ID> _
  Select IdEl
```

But now I have a requirement that the program deal with more documents, some of them have different namespaces.  This particular method only has to deal with one particular namespace, so I though writing this would work:

```
Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load("my.xml")
Dim ns As XNamespace = "http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2"
Dim IDElemCollect As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = _
  From IdEl In doc ...<ns:ItemID>.<ns:ID> _
  Select IdEl
```

But the VS2013 compiler complains that 
Error   1   XML namespace prefix 'ns' is not defined.

and, obviously, if I don't use the namespace, my select finds nothing.  Is there another way to write this select to use the namespace?

Comment: Why not import multiple namespaces with different prefixes, per [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384589.aspx).  e.g. `Imports <xmlns:ns1="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2">` and `Imports <xmlns:ns2="http://schema.infor.com/SomethingElse">`.  You can leave one as the default (your current `Imports`) if you want.  You can then use those prefixes in your select.

Comment: Thanks, I figured that out almost as quickly as you answered it, but that's the way I ended up going, see the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is a big difference between

```
Imports <xmlns="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2">
```

and using an XNamespace

```
Dim ns As XNamespace = "http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2"
```

So, what I ended up doing was defining several named Globalnamespaces, and using them by name when I needed them:  So

```
Imports <xmlns:ns="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2">
Imports <xmlns:nw="http://some.other.schema/blah">

Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load("my.xml")
Dim IDElemCollect As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = _
 From IdEl In doc ...<ns:ItemID>.<ns:ID> _
 Select IdEl
```

And the named globalnamespace can be represented as shown in the Select statement.